# Sort and print in line

Tags: awk

Input:

```
54578787 -58    1
6578999 -658-   3
1352413 -541-   11
4564564 -23-    11
654564  -65-    3
6543564 -65-    1
```

Desired output:

```
column3 = 1,3,11
```

Using:

```
a=$(awk '{print $3}' text | sort -u | paste -s -d,) && paste <(echo "column3 =") <(echo $a)
```

I only get:

```
column3 = [large blank] 1,11,3
```

---

Other issue: If I remove all hyphens on the second column, I get

```
column3 = [large blank] ,1,11,3
```

I think it's a paste command issue.

Last but not least: why do I have `1,11,3` instead of `1,3,11`?

Comment: Is that the desired output because it's the order the values first appear in the input file or because if you sorted those numbers numerically that's the order you'd get? The former has a MUCH simpler solution than the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
 echo "column3 = $(awk '{print $3}' test.txt |sort -nu |  paste -s -d, )"
```

gives me

```
column3 = 1,3,11
```

One key element is to sort with the `-n` option to do numerical sorting.

---

It also works with the hyphens deleted:

```
echo "column3 = $(tr -d - < test.txt| awk '{print $3}'  |sort -nu |  paste -s -d, )"
```

also outputs

```
column3 = 1,3,11
```

Comment: your first solution does not work at all. Second solutions gives a correct answer on text with hyphens, and gives column3=,1,3,11 on text without hyphens

Comment: Yes, I used the wrong input data for the first part. However, my solution still works when I remove the hyphens, how have you removed them?

Comment: mmm... interesting: when I try tr -d - < file | awk '{print $3}' | sort -nu | paste -s -d, I have got ,1,3,11

Comment: what version do you have please? do you mean coreutils or awk are bugged?

Comment: got it echo "column3 = $(tr -d - < test.txt| awk '{print $3}'  |sort -nu | grep -v '^$' |  paste -s -d, )" thank you very much martin all other guys who left some posts here !

Comment: @blue_xylo you had a leading empty line in your data.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use awk:

```
$ awk '{a[$3]} END {printf "column3 = "; for (i in a) {printf "%d%s", i, (++v==length(a)?"\n":",")}}' file
column3 = 1,3,11
```

#### Explanation

- `a[$3]` populate the `a[]` array with the 3rd column. This way, any new value will create a new index.
- `END {}` perform commands after processing the whole file.
- `printf "column3 = "` prints `"column3 ="`.
- `for (i in a) {printf "%d%s", i, (++v==length(a)?"\n":",")}` loop through the stored values and print them comma separated, unless it is the last one.

---

Your current solution would work like this:

```
$ paste -d" " <(echo "column3 =") <(awk '{print $3}' file | sort -u | paste -s -d,)
column3 = 1,11,3
```

Note there is no need to store in `$a`. And to have just one space, use `paste -d" "`.

And to have it sorted numerically? Just add `-n` to your `sort`:

```
$ paste -d" " <(echo "column3 =") <(awk '{print $3}' file | sort -nu | paste -s -d,)
column3 = 1,3,11
```

With this command you get the same output, no matter the hyphens.

Comment: I was studying this part now. Just edited, with `-n` you get the sort output. Otherwise 11 goes before 3 because it is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: in both cases (text with and without hyphens) I have an error msg: "awk: line 1: illegal reference to array a
"

Comment: @blue_xylo strange... Give a try with `{a[$3]++}` for example in the first block.

Comment: @fedorqui does your awk (the first) solution do any sorting?

Comment: @Kent no. I do not have the GNU awk you mention to use `asorti()`.

Answer (score 1):

If perl is acceptable:

```
perl -lanE '
    $c3{$F[2]} = 1; 
    END {say "column3 = ", join(",", sort {$a <=> $b} keys %c3)}
' file
```

Comment: +1 .. and people complain `perl` is not readable (better choice of variables would have helped but considering it is a one-liner it doesn't really matter)!

Answer (score 0):

my gawk line looks like:

```
awk '{a[$3]} END{c=asorti(a,d,"@val_num_asc"); printf "column3 = ";
     for(x=1;x<=c;x++)printf "%d%s", d[x],(c==x?"\n":",")}' file
```

output:

```
column3 = 1,3,11
```

### Note

- you need gawk to run that (asorti function)
- sorting ascending as numbers
- output in single line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you truly want the numbers sorted and not just reproduced in the order they are first seen:

```
$ awk '{print $3}' file | sort -nu | awk '{s=(NR>1?s",":"")$0} END{print "column3 =",s}'
column3 = 1,3,11
```

You were getting `1,11,3` because without the `-n` arg for `sort` you are sorting alphabetically instead of numerically and the first char of `11` (i.e. `1`) comes before the first char of `3`.